# Can I safely prepare these dishes ahead of time?

Tags: food-safety, refrigerator

I'm making some dishes for an event. Due to constraints in my schedule I'm thinking of making them ahead of time.

The first is a Buffalo Chicken Dip, it is mainly a bought cooked rotisserie chicken and cream cheese.
The second is Kimchi-ppang which contains pork, kimchi and dough.

I'd like to assemble it to the point of a final bake (the dip is mixed, the pork is cooked and the dough unbaked) for both and then store it in the fridge for about 3 days. Will this be safe to do? I may be able to make it fresh on the day, but I'd have to rush a lot.

Comment: The generic question should answer all your questions about food safety. You may want to browse through the site with regards to making the dough ahead (assuming that it’s a yeasted dough).